# please help to make group by

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT      dbo.employee.firstname,dbo.employee.lastname,dbo.employee.phone,
            dbo.project.code_proj,dbo.project.proj_name,dbo.project.customer 
FROM        dbo.proj_details  
               INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON proj_details.id_emp=employee.id_emp 
               INNER JOIN dbo.project ON proj_details.code_proj=project.code_proj
               group by employee.firstname
```

Comment: the group by didnt work

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Voting to close because this site is for advanced T-SQL questions whereas it seems you are be asking for help with a basic query construct. When asking SQL questions, include a script with DDL (CREATE TABLE statements), sample data (INSERT statements), the query you tried, any error messages/unexpected results,
and the results you expect.

Comment: did you get an error message? If so, add it to your post

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `GROUP BY` clause in a query, what it does is effectively collapses the rows that share the values of all of the fields in the `GROUP BY` into one row. When this happens, because every row that was collapsed into one row shares the same values in the fields of the `GROUP BY`, you can then directly `SELECT` those fields.

But any other columns that were not part of the `GROUP BY` clause could have varying values across the collapsed rows, and therefore there is no way to directly `SELECT` those columns themselves (since it's not possible to display two different values from two different rows when there's only one row being displayed, due to the grouping).

Rather you need to use an [**Aggregate Function**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), e.g. `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()`, `COUNT()` etc, to be able to `SELECT` any columns that weren't part of the `GROUP BY` clause.

So in your example, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT dbo.employee.firstname,MAX(dbo.employee.lastname) AS lastname,MAX(dbo.employee.phone) AS phone,
    MAX(dbo.project.code_proj) AS code_proj,MAX(dbo.project.proj_name) AS proj_name,MAX(dbo.project.customer) AS customer
FROM dbo.proj_details  
INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON proj_details.id_emp=employee.id_emp 
INNER JOIN dbo.project ON proj_details.code_proj=project.code_proj
group by employee.firstname
```

Keep in mind that since you're only grouping on `firstname`, the `MAX(lastname)` can and likely will be different than the `MIN(lastname)` for each grouped `firstname` (as is true for the rest of the ungrouped fields). This is because *John Smith* will group up with *John Doe* by their `firstname` of *John*. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish this may be ok or it may not be.

Alternatively if you don't want to collapse the rows only on `firstname` and have the ability to see the different `lastname`, `phone`, etc then you can add those columns to the `GROUP BY` clause as well, like so:

```
SELECT dbo.employee.firstname,dbo.employee.lastname,dbo.employee.phone,
        dbo.project.code_proj,dbo.project.proj_name,dbo.project.customer
FROM dbo.proj_details  
INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON proj_details.id_emp=employee.id_emp 
INNER JOIN dbo.project ON proj_details.code_proj=project.code_proj
group by employee.firstname,dbo.employee.lastname,dbo.employee.phone,dbo.project.code_proj,dbo.project.proj_name,dbo.project.customer
```

This will basically just remove all duplicate rows by those columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, and when you don't need aggregation on any particular column, is logically equivalent to using the `DISTINCT` keyword like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.employee.firstname,dbo.employee.lastname,dbo.employee.phone,
        dbo.project.code_proj,dbo.project.proj_name,dbo.project.customer
FROM dbo.proj_details  
INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON proj_details.id_emp=employee.id_emp 
INNER JOIN dbo.project ON proj_details.code_proj=project.code_proj
```

Which type of query you need depends on the details of your use case which you've forgotten to include. Unfortunately there's a pretty good chance your question may get closed because of its lack of context. If you could please update your question with what your Tables structure looks like, and what your end goal is by trying to use `GROUP BY` (e.g. are you trying to remove all duplicates?, are you trying to get the first `phone` for each `firstname` and `lastname`?, are you trying to count how many `code_proj` each `customer` has?), then we'll be able to better help you on this forum.

For more information on the `GROUP BY` clause, please see this [W3Schools guide](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) on it to get a beginner's intro. Then you can look into the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on it.